# how to change border-bottom-color in angular material (table)

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image]i use of angular material(table) for show users list, and get user of server,
now if user is number 0, show border-bottom-color red,and if number 1, show border-bottom-color green and .... ,I've done it, but it only runs once,
please help me

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>date</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let orderList">{{ orderList.date }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>


  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>


    <mat-row [style.border-bottom]="
      user.status == 0 ? '3px solid red' : ''||
      user.status == 1 ? '3px solid green' : ''||
      user.status == 2 ? '3px solid blue' : ''||
      user.status == 3 ? '3px solid skyBleu' : ''||
      user.status == 4 ? '3px solid purple' : ''||
      user.status == 5 ? '3px solid #254e54' : ''
      "
      [routerLink]="['/showOrder']"
      routerLinkActive="router-link-active" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
      fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    </mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by works only once? is it means when you refresh it will not work or any other thing. Please make it clear a bit

Comment: i mean It checks the first user. and set border color user one for all user and it is wrong. and every user has border-bottom-color himself

Comment: please make a stackblitz so that the problem would be clear for all of us

Comment: i mean it is, Each number has a specific  border-bottom-color , number 1 color green and number 2 color blue and number 0 color red, number 3 color purple,Now based on border-bottom-color changes border-bottom-color users ,but changes border-bottom-color all user based on The first user number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use row.user instead of user.status
Live Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-border)

**Explanation**:

When you use user.status it will get from the your object getting from server. As it matches first condition user.status == 0, all the rows are styled with that color. But when you use row.user, it will check for each row and style according to the condition. Thus it solved your problem.